# Installing Semantic-UI with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, semantic-ui

I've been using Semantic UI with Rails for a bit of time, and I've always relied on the semantic-ui-sass gem for installation.

Yesterday, I came to the conclusion that the gem hasn't been updated with the newest version of Semantic UI. I can only support this through anecdote, as several predefined UI styles didn't have any effect, such as:

```
<div class="ui pink message">
```

and any padded grids, or teal columns. So I decided to download the source and to merely drag and drop and let the asset pipeline do the rest. But then I had some questions, and here I am. So,

1) All the CSS is done with LESS. Doesn't rails use Sass by default? Can I merely drop the folder with all the LESS files, require it in application.css, and it will work? Or is there an intermediary step?

2) There are a couple of themes included in the source. How do I implement them?

3) Is there anything else I need to know, that I haven't realized to ask?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can user gem 'bower-rails' and use semantic-ui from there.
2. Drop the sass-rails and use gem 'less-rails'
3. Require the 'semantic-ui' folder in your application.css and application.js
4. Regarding the theme, I can figure that out yet.